# Socket.IO events getting too much time to fire

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, chatbot

I am using [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) for my chat app. (HTML + JS & node js). It's working fine and great when one client connects to it.

But when another window is opened to start the chat, the chat becomes very slow. When three or four users connect to the chat at the same time, it's getting even slower such that, it looks like, it's almost freezed.

FYI, throughout the application, I have used `socket.emit()` (with & without callbacks). My requirement is, receive a message from the client, respond to the client. The user will chat with a bot (server). Said that, the message sent by the user (to the server) will not be sent to any other users. So, I found that `socket.emit()` is the right way to deal with in this case.

Am I getting it wrong? Should I use some other way for emitting?

**Note:-**

The application works perfectly when running inside the enide studio with the inbuilt node js server. But, when deployed, the events are extremely slow.

**Update:-**

I tried initiating a chat in chrome and another chat in IE. Same problem. So, the problem is not from the client end.

**Update 2:-**
When I debugged, I saw that the problem was with `socket.emit()` **with callbacks**. Below is the snippet which is causing the problem

```
//socketRouter.js
exports.requestData = function(callback)
{
    console.log("check 1");
    this.socket.emit('requestData',callback);
}

//flow.js
    function flow()
    {
        pipeline([
                socketRouter.requestData,
                processData
                ],
           {socket:socket});
    }


var pipeline = function(funcs, scope) {
    (function next() {
        if(funcs.length > 0) {
              funcs.shift().apply(scope || {}, [next].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
              console.log("check 2");
          }
    })();
};

function processData()
{
    console.length("check 3");  
    //process continues...
}

//client side
socket.on('requestData', function(callback) {
        console.log("UI check");
        if(typeof callback === "function")
            callback(data);
});
```

And in console, I'm getting a huge time gap between *check 2* & *check 3*.

Below is the console log

```
check 1 
check 2
//program freezes here for sometime.
check 3
```

I'm starting to wonder whether it's really the problem with `socket.emit()` or the `pipeline()` function. But the `pipeline()` function works perfectly fine in all other parts of the application.

Comment: And how should we help you? Do proper debugging. Analyze your codes memory usage and determine where the performance goes. If you want us to help, show your servers code

Comment: @JonasW. ,thanks for pointing out. Added the code. See my update2.

Comment: The gap is there cause you send a function hook to the client over a long long wire, then the client calls it and it takes the path over the long long wire back to the server. What do you expect?

Comment: But it works fine when there is only one client commented to the application. I need a server function to be called from the client end. What do you suggest? Avoiding the pipeline usage while using this kinda callbacks? Or completely rewrite the whole architecture without any such callbacks?